# Template function for detecting pointer like (dereferencable) types fails for actual pointer types

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming, sfinae

I am trying to write a mechanism to detect if a type is a *pointer like* type. By that I mean it is dereferencable through `operator*()` and `operator->()`.

I have three different structs that are specialized accordingly:

1. `is_pointer_like_dereferencable` which checks for `operator*()`
2. `is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable` which checks for `operator->()`
3. `is_pointer_like` which simply combines 1 & 2

I added specializations for non-templated types like `int, int*, ...` and for templated types like `std::vector<...>, std::shared_ptr<...>, ...`.

However, it seems that I made a mistake when implementing `is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable`. The relevant code is

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable : std::false_type 
{
};

template <typename T>
struct is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable<T, std::enable_if_t<
                                                std::is_pointer_v<T> ||
                                                std::is_same_v<decltype(std::declval<T>().operator->()), std::add_pointer_t<T>>>
    > : std::true_type
{
};


template <template <typename...> typename P, typename T, typename... R>
struct is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable<P<T, R...>, std::enable_if_t<
                                                std::is_same_v<decltype(std::declval<P<T, R...>>().operator->()), std::add_pointer_t<T>>>
    > : std::true_type
{
};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable_v = is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable<T>::value;
```

The 2nd struct should check if a non-templated type is either an actual pointer type or if the type does have an arrow operator that returns a pointer to itself. But when I test the mechanism with the code below, pointer types (like `int*` are not detected correctly). Why is that?

```
template <typename T>
struct Test
{
    T& operator*()
    {
        return *this;
    }

    T* operator->()
    {
        return this;
    }
};   

void main()
{
    bool
        a = is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable_v<int>, // false
        b = is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable_v<int*>, // false, should be true
        c = is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable_v<vector<int>>, // false
        d = is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable_v<vector<int>*>, // false, should be true
        e = is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable_v<Test<int>>, // true
        f = is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable_v<Test<int>*>, // false, should be true
        g = is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable_v<shared_ptr<int>>, // true
        h = is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable_v<shared_ptr<int>*>, // false, should be true
        i = is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable_v<int***>; // false
}
```

The `is_pointer_like_dereferencable` struct only differs at the `std::is_same_v<...>` part and it does detect actual pointer types correctly.

The fact that it fails to detect pointer types (which should be covered by `std::is_pointer_v<...>`) doesn't make any sense to me. Can someone explain this?

Comment: Why should `is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable_v<int*>` be true?  What does it means to use `->` on an `int*`?

Comment: `int*` is indeed a bad example for that but you can dereference any pointer type with `->`. I.e. `auto x = new std::vector<int>; x->push_back(10);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But when I test the mechanism with the code below, pointer types (like int* are not detected correctly). Why is that?

S.F.I.N.A.E.: Substitution Failure Is Not An Error

So, for `int*`, from `decltype(std::declval<T>().operator->()` you get a substitution failure and the specialization isn't considered. So is used the general form, so `std::false`

You should write **two** specializations: one or pointers and one for `operator->()` enabled classes.

Bonus answer: instead of type traits as `is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable` (overcomplicated, IMHO), I propose you to pass through a set of helper functions (only declared)

```
template <typename>
std::false_type is_pointer_like (unsigned long);

template <typename T>
auto is_pointer_like (int)
   -> decltype( * std::declval<T>(), std::true_type{} );

template <typename T>
auto is_pointer_like (long)
   -> decltype( std::declval<T>().operator->(), std::true_type{} );
```

so `is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable` can be simply written as a `using`

```
template <typename T>
using is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable = decltype(is_pointer_like<T>(0));
```

with helper `is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable_v`

```
template <typename T>
static auto const is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable_v
   = is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable<T>::value;
```

The following is a full working example

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

template <typename>
std::false_type is_pointer_like (unsigned long);

template <typename T>
auto is_pointer_like (int)
   -> decltype( * std::declval<T>(), std::true_type{} );

template <typename T>
auto is_pointer_like (long)
   -> decltype( std::declval<T>().operator->(), std::true_type{} );

template <typename T>
using is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable = decltype(is_pointer_like<T>(0));

template <typename T>
static auto const is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable_v
   = is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable<T>::value;


template <typename T>
struct Test
 {
   T & operator*  () { return *this; }
   T * operator-> () { return  this; }
 }; 

int main()
 {
   std::cout << is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable_v<int>
      << std::endl, // false
   std::cout << is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable_v<int*>
      << std::endl, // true
   std::cout << is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable_v<std::vector<int>>
      << std::endl, // false
   std::cout << is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable_v<std::vector<int>*>
      << std::endl, // true
   std::cout << is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable_v<Test<int>>
      << std::endl, // true
   std::cout << is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable_v<Test<int>*>
      << std::endl, // true
   std::cout << is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable_v<std::shared_ptr<int>>
      << std::endl, // true
   std::cout << is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable_v<std::shared_ptr<int>*>
      << std::endl, // true
   std::cout << is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable_v<int***>
      << std::endl; // true
 }
```

Comment: I get the point. And changing the implementation accordingly fixes the problem. But why is `operator->()` not defined for pointer types when they actually can be accessed via `->`?

Comment: because `operator->()` is a function; `decltype(std::declval<T>().operator->())` give you the type returned by a **function** `operator->()` in `T`. With a pointer to a generic `struct` (by example) you can use the arrow operator but (generally speaking) isn't defined a function `operator->()`

Comment: @Timo - answer improved with an alternative way to write `is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable`; hope this helps

Comment: That is actually a neat solution. But I think you changed the semantics of  `is_pointer_like`. In my case it's defined as `is_pointer_like = is_pointer_like_dereferencable && is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable`. Also I don't understand the 2nd overload. Why `std::declval<T>()->operator->()`? Shouldn't this be `std::declval<T>().operator->()`?

Comment: @Timo - sorry but I don't see, in your code example, `is_pointer_like_dereferencable`; I've tried to rewrite your example; obviously you can modify it to obtain a different semantic. Regarding the second overload... you're rigth: is `std::declval<T>().operator->()`; sorry; answer corrected.

Comment: I've written the relations of the different structs at the top of my question, but it's alright. I understand what you mean. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Timo - Yes, but the example is a little different and this confused me; anyway, following the example of `is_pointer_like()`, should be simple to write a couple of set of declared template functions: one for `is_pointer_like_dereferencable` and one for `is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable`.

Comment: using `overload_tag<N>` is more readable than remember priority order versus `int`, `long`, `unsigned long`.

Comment: This answer doesn't work correctly. First of all, Test return the wrong types (you can't convert Test to int). After fixing that (thats just the test code) when you comment out `operator->` in Test it still prints 1 for is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable_v<Test<int>>.

Comment: @CarloWood - It's passed more that a year from this question so I don't remember well... anyway, it seems to me that you're right regarding the `Test` wrong return type (I'm surprised that the compiler doesn't warn about it) but, as you can see, I've simply copied the `Test` class from the question. But, given that you comment `operator->()`, why `is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable_v<Test<int>>` shoudn't be `1`: the `operator* ()` is still present.

Comment: @max66 Great solution :)
Nit-picking: It should be `dereferenceable`, with an additional **e**.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use [`std::experimental::is_detected`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) and then simply have:

```
template <typename T> dereferencable_type = decltype(*declval<T>());
template <typename T> arrow_type = decltype(declval<T>().operator->());

template <typename T> is_dereferencable =
    std::experimental::is_detected<dereferencable_type, T>;
template <typename T> has_arrow = std::experimental::is_detected<arrow_type, T>;
```

and then compose those traits:

```
template <typename T>
using is_pointer_like_dereferencable = is_dereferencable<T>;

template <typename T>
is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable = std::disjunction<std::is_pointer<T>, has_arrow<T>>;

template <typename T>
std::is_pointer_like = std::conjunction<is_pointer_like_dereferencable<T>,
                                        is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable<T>>;
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm on Windows and it looks like msvc doesn't support `experimental/type_traits` right now. Btw. your definition of `arrow_type`  queries `operator()` insted of `operator->()`.

Comment: @Timo: link provides possible implementation. Typo fixed Btw.

Answer (score 1):

First off, this specialization is at best pointless, but actually wrong:

```
template <template <typename...> typename P, typename T, typename... R>
struct is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable<P<T, R...>,
    std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_same_v<
            decltype(std::declval<P<T, R...>>().operator->()), 
            std::add_pointer_t<T>>>
    > : std::true_type
{ };
```

There isn't anything special about class template specializations with all type parameters when it comes to being pointer-like. So you shouldn't need to treat `P<T, R...>` any differently than just `T`.

Now, this specialization also has problems:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable<T,
    std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_pointer_v<T> ||
        std::is_same_v<decltype(std::declval<T>().operator->()), std::add_pointer_t<T>>>
    > : std::true_type
{
};
```

First, raw pointers don't have `.operator->()`. That makes the whole boolean expression ill-formed, which causes the entire specialization to get thrown out. Short circuiting happens on an expression by expression basis, but each expression still has to be valid.

Second, `->` doesn't have to return `add_pointer_t<T>`. `std::vector<X>::iterator::operator->` returns an `X*`, not an `iterator*`. So that's just checking the wrong thing.

We can let the base case check for pointers, and just let the specialization check for `.operator->` across all types (whether they're class template specializations or not):

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable
    : std::is_pointer<T>
{ };

template <typename T>
struct is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable<T, 
    void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().operator->())>
    >
: std::true_type
{ };
```

That said, `is_pointer` probably isn't sufficient since it doesn't make sense for `int*` to be "arrow dereferenceable". So you probably want to do something like:

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable
    : std::false_type
{ };

template <typename T>
struct is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable<T*, void>
    : std::disjunction<std::is_class<T>, std::is_union<T>>
{ };
```

Or some such.

Comment: I did the `P<T, R...>` specialization only to check for the return type, haven't thought about the case you pointed out with the iterator. So I guess I can remove the whole specialization.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Jarod42's answer (which doesn't compile for me), I created the following code snippet (C++17),

```
#include "sys.h"    // Required for libcwd (debug output).
#include "debug.h"  // Required for libcwd (debug output).
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Start of implementation.

#include <experimental/type_traits>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T> using dereferencable_type =
    decltype(*std::declval<T>());
template<typename T> using arrow_type =
    decltype(std::declval<T>().operator->());

template<typename T> using is_dereferencable =
    std::experimental::is_detected<dereferencable_type, T>;

template<typename T> using has_arrow =
    std::experimental::is_detected<arrow_type, T>;

template<typename T> using is_pointer_like_dereferencable =
    is_dereferencable<T>;

template<typename T> using is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable =
    std::disjunction<std::is_pointer<T>, has_arrow<T>>;

template <typename T> using is_pointer_like =
    std::conjunction<is_pointer_like_dereferencable<T>,
                     is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable<T>>;

template<typename T> inline constexpr bool is_pointer_like_dereferencable_v =
    is_pointer_like_dereferencable<T>::value;
template<typename T> inline constexpr bool is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable_v =
    is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable<T>::value;
template<typename T> inline constexpr bool is_pointer_like_v =
    is_pointer_like<T>::value;

// End of implementation
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template<typename T>
struct TestNone
{
  static int const n;
};

template<typename T>
struct TestRef : public TestNone<T>
{
  T const& operator*() { return TestNone<T>::n; }
};

template<typename T>
struct TestArrow : public TestNone<T>
{
  TestArrow const* operator->() { return this; }
};

template<typename T>
struct TestBoth : virtual public TestRef<T>, virtual public TestArrow<T>
{
};

//static
template<typename T>
int const TestNone<T>::n = 42;

template<typename T>
void test()
{
  Dout(dc::notice|continued_cf, '"' <<
      libcwd::type_info_of<T>().demangled_name() << "\" is ");
  bool something = true;
  if (is_pointer_like_v<T>)
    Dout(dc::continued, "pointer-like.");
  else
  {
    if (is_pointer_like_arrow_dereferencable_v<T>)
      Dout(dc::continued, "arrow dereferencable; ");
    else
      something = is_pointer_like_dereferencable_v<T>;
    if (is_pointer_like_dereferencable_v<T>)
      Dout(dc::continued, "dereferencable; ");
  }
  if (!something)
    Dout(dc::continued, "not a pointer or pointer-like.");
  Dout(dc::finish, "");
}

int main()
{
  Debug(NAMESPACE_DEBUG::init());

  test<int>();
  test<int*>();
  test<std::vector<int>>();
  test<std::vector<int>*>();
  test<std::shared_ptr<int>>();
  test<std::shared_ptr<int>*>();
  test<std::shared_ptr<int***>>();
  test<TestNone<int>>();
  test<TestNone<int>*>();
  test<TestRef<int>>();
  test<TestRef<int>*>();
  test<TestArrow<int>>();
  test<TestArrow<int>*>();
  test<TestBoth<int>>();
  test<TestBoth<int>*>();
}
```

where `sys.h` and `debug.h` are 'standard' headers from the git submodule [cwds](https://github.com/CarloWood/cwds).

This prints the following debug output:

> NOTICE  : "`int`" is not a pointer or pointer-like.
>   NOTICE  : "`int*`" is pointer-like.
>   NOTICE  : "`std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >`" is not a pointer or pointer-like.
>   NOTICE  : "`std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >*`" is pointer-like.
>   NOTICE  : "`std::shared_ptr<int>`" is pointer-like.
>   NOTICE  : "`std::shared_ptr<int>*`" is pointer-like.
>   NOTICE  : "`std::shared_ptr<int***>`" is pointer-like.
>   NOTICE  : "`TestNone<int>`" is not a pointer or pointer-like.
>   NOTICE  : "`TestNone<int>*`" is pointer-like.
>   NOTICE  : "`TestRef<int>`" is dereferencable;
>   NOTICE  : "`TestRef<int>*`" is pointer-like.
>   NOTICE  : "`TestArrow<int>`" is arrow dereferencable;
>   NOTICE  : "`TestArrow<int>*`" is pointer-like.
>   NOTICE  : "`TestBoth<int>`" is pointer-like.
>   NOTICE  : "`TestBoth<int>*`" is pointer-like.