# How to check whether variable of given type can be dereferenced?

Tags: c++, type-traits

Is there way in C++ to determine whether type of variable is pointer or any iterator with overloaded `operator*`?

There is standard `std::is_pointer`, but it say nothing about iterators.

I wanna use it in code like this:

```cpp
template<class T>
void func(T var)
{
    if constexpr (can_be_dereferenced<T>::value)
    {
        // do something with *var;
    }
}
```

Comment: All standard library iterators have certain well defined members, like `value_type`. You should be able to come up with some SFINAE-based approach that checks for their existence. Or, make use of `std::iterator_traits`.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49904914/11224588

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically want to check if `*var` is valid. This is the perfect use case for a SFINAE check:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

namespace detail {
    // If `*(object of type T)` is valid, this is selected and
    // the return type is `std::true_type`
    template<class T>
    decltype(static_cast<void>(*std::declval<T>()), std::true_type{})
    can_be_dereferenced_impl(int);

    // Otherwise the less specific function is selected,
    // and the return type is `std::false_type`
    template<class>
    std::false_type can_be_dereferenced_impl(...);
}

template<class T>
struct can_be_dereferenced : decltype(detail::can_be_dereferenced_impl<T>(0)) {};

template<class T>
void func(T var)
{
    if constexpr (can_be_dereferenced<T&>::value)
    // Or         can_be_dereferenced<decltype((var))>::value
    {
        auto&& dereferenced = *var;
        // Use dereferenced
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You might do it in this way using compile time function overload resolution and SFINAE:

```
template<class T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer<T>::value>>
void func(T var)
{
  // a pointer
}

template<class T, typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_pointer<T>::value>,
         typename = T::value_type>
void func(T var)
{
  // possibly an iterator
}

int main()
{
  int *i = new int(11);
  func(i); // Calls the first overload

  std::vector<int> v;
  std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = v.begin();

  func(it); // Calls the second overload

  func(2); // Fail, as there is no function for this argument.
  [..]
```